# Correct usage of "whose"?

Tags: whose

I was wondering if it is correct to repeat "whose" after "and"? More precisely, assume I want do describe an object, say a chair of width 50cm and height 1 meter. Then which of the following is correct:

> This is a chair whose width is 50cm and *whose* height is 1 meter.

or

> This is a chair whose width is 50cm and *its* height is 1 meter.

or of course none of the above!

Comment: This question belongs on [ell.se] -- Suggesting migration.

Comment: You might hear the second version in imprecise conversation, but the first version, with the balanced relative wh-clauses, is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reads better to me: it's well-constructed, and repeating the 'whose' clarifies the sentence, although it *could* be shortened to "... whose width is 50cm and height 1 meter".  The second sentence is really two statements, as if you're saying "This is a chair whose width is 50cm. And its height is 1 meter."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer. Just to make sure, can I shorten the second sentence by removing the verb *is* without making it grammatically incorrect (as you did)?

Comment: Yes you can, but it might be regarded as rather poetic, as in "To err is human, to forgive [is] divine." I've forgotten the name for this structure  -  someone will tell us. For clarity, I'd go with your first sentence.

Comment: We can use "comments" to post our opinions, instead.

Comment: Sorry, Kris, where did I err?

Comment: @DavidGarner How do you feel about "... chair whose ...", though? I was about to ask my own question: "whom is to whose as which is to ...?" Colloquially we hear "chair thats" or the even more awkward "chair whichs", but I do not believe either to be correct.

Comment: @OllieFord I think " ... chair whose ..." is correct.  I'd never thought about  this before, but 'which' doesn't have a [one-word] possessive form *except* 'whose'.  In order to stick to 'which', you'd have to say "The chair of which the width is ..." which is terribly clumsy.  Likewise 'that' used as a relative pronoun doesn't have a possessive "that" or "that's".  But you could simplify the whole thing by skipping relative pronouns: The chair of width 50 cm and height 1 meter."